# How to clear text box on focus ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want this converted to razor

```
<input type="text" value="A new value" onfocus="if(this.value=='A new value') this.value='';">
```

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: You can wire javascript blur event to do so

Comment: Hello... I am trying to clear textbox value on focus using mvc razor

Comment: Actually the html version works just fine but need to convert to MVC Razor

Comment: <input type="text" value="A new value" onfocus="if(this.value=='A new value') this.value='';">     //This is the working HTML

Comment: yeah , then just add it in HtmlAttributes , along with other Attributes you have

Comment: want to convert to MVC Razor and failing...

Comment: let me try again

Comment: I want World Peace

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Html.TextBox("ter", null, 
new { @class = "form-control date-picker input-sm",
      @id = "form_control_1",
      @autocomplete = "off",
      @Value = "mm/dd/yyyy" ,
      onfocus="if(this.value=='A new value') this.value='';"})
```

I am not sure what you are trying to implement but if textbox has `A new value` as a text and you focus on that , it will clear textbox

Hope that helps

Comment: this is what i was looking for however the code still does not run @vishal